# How to invoke an Eclipse plugin from command line?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

if I have a plugin that validates code in Eclipse to a particular standard/spec, is it possible to invoke that plugin from the command line, passing source files as arguments?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example:

```
java -jar plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.0.v20070523.jar -consoleLog 

-console -nosplash -application Console.ConsoleStatistics file:///c:/temp/test.aaxl
```

From: [https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/aadl/index.php/Creating_Headless_(Command_Line)_Plugins](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/aadl/index.php/Creating_Headless_%28Command_Line%29_Plugins)

Answer (score 3):

You can create new headless application and run it through the command line. Here is a simple "hello word" example.

http://www.developertesting.com/archives/month200508/20050823-HeadlessHelloWorldInEclipse.html